# Checking a box in one Column using a value from another column in the same Table with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, nunit, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with Selenium in C# (ChromeDriver) using NUnit for testing and hit a snag on this. We have a table that dynamically loads various Products based on what is enabled for that account.
I'm trying to write tests around it to order each individual product but I have a snag with marking a box checked. The table just uses an numerical ID with a separate column used for the Product Name (See HTML Code Below).

There is a hidden field that contains the Product Name but I've been told in the past that Selenium cannot see it unless it is visible.

Any help or ideas would be a great start for me getting this resolved.

```
<td align="center" valign="top">
    <input id="reports11.selected1" name="reports[11].selected" onclick="javascript:doCheckbox(11, false)" style="margin-top:5px" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="_reports[11].selected" value="on">
    <input id="reports11.productClassId" name="reports[11].productClassId" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input id="reports11.productId" name="reports[11].productId" type="hidden" value="99599">
    <input id="reports11.name" name="reports[11].name" type="hidden" value="Product Build - TEST">
</td>

<td align="center" valign="top">
    <select id="reports11.priority" name="reports[11].priority" style="width:40px;padding:1px;margin: 0 0 0 0" onchange="javascript:doPriority(11)">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">--</option>
    </select>
</td>

<td valign="top">
    Product Build - TEST
</td>
```

Comment: If you just need value of hidden field it should be easy. First get IWebElement using some GetElementBy method, then call GetAttribute("value") on the IWebElement you got and then you can use Selenium helper for select => SelectElement and its SelectByValue method.

Comment: Where are your code attempts? You reference "See Code Below" but there is none. You need to be more specific with what you are trying to do and what isn't working. You reference "marking a box checked" but you didn't state which one... there are 5 INPUTs and a SELECT. Is "Product Build - Test" supposed to be the product name? You have example HTML which is good... now add references to that HTML in your question to clear up your question.

Comment: @JeffC Sorry, made a typo on that. Basically, in the HTML Table, there is a checkbox that I can check via the Automation using Selenium (there are 50 Products with checkboxes). What I'm attempting to do is check only one of the checkboxes based on the Product Name displayed in the <td valign="top">Product Build - TEST</td> line. When I try this Selenium cannot see the checkbox in the above area as the Reports(X) changes.

Comment: There are 5 INPUT tags there... 4 are hidden but one is not... have you tried clicking/interacting with that one?

Comment: Yes and that works. However I also have to write it for a dynamic table as well so while the one above says Reports11 is basically "Product Build - TEST", on the next test it could be Reports16 for "Product Build - TEST". So I'm can see the name in the Hidden input tag but if i try to call it, Selenium cannot see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code assume the checkbox at the 1st column and the product name at the 3rd column.

```
public void chooseProductbyName(productName)
{
 string xpath = "//tr[td[3][text()='"+productName+"']]/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox']";
 driver.findElement(by.xpath(xpath)).click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just couldn't wrap my head around how to do this with a Dynamically generated list table.